# Flutter Changing Colour of the Icon With Container

Tags: flutter

I would like to ask how can i change the color of my icon when I navigate to the next page that means when I select the page the icon is blue then the unselected icon will remain grey. I have tried `setState()` but it's not working for me.

```dart
class _CustomBottomNavigationState extends State<CustomBottomNavigation> {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: 80,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(size.width, 80),
            painter: BNBCustomPainter(),
          ),
          Center(
            heightFactor: 0.6,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                widget._addingThings(context);
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              elevation:0.1,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: size.width,
            height: 80,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: MyScreen(), isIos: true));

                }),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: My2Screen()));

                }),
                Container(width: size.width * 0.2),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {
                  _pickImageFromCamera();
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => My3Screen()));
                }),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: My4Screen()));

                }),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom widget for your icon buttons and maintain the selected/unselected state internally within that widget.

```dart
class CustomIconButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function onTap;

  CustomIconButton({required this.icon, required this.isSelected, required this.onTap});

  @override
  _CustomIconButtonState createState() => _CustomIconButtonState();
}

class _CustomIconButtonState extends State<CustomIconButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        widget.icon,
        color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
      ),
      onPressed: widget.onTap,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```dart
Container(
  width: size.width,
  height: 80,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      CustomIconButton(
        icon: Icons.home,
        isSelected: currentPageIndex == 0,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() => currentPageIndex = 0;

          Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: MY4Screen(), isIos: true));
        },
      ),
      CustomIconButton(
        icon: Icons.notifications,
        isSelected: currentPageIndex == 1,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() => currentPageIndex = 1;
       
          Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: ReminderScreen()));
        },
      ),
      Container(width: size.width * 0.2),
      CustomIconButton(
        icon: Icons.abc,
        isSelected: currentPageIndex == 2,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() => currentPageIndex = 2;

          _pickImageFromCamera();
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyScreen()));
        },
      ),
      CustomIconButton(
        icon: Icons.ac_unit,
        isSelected: currentPageIndex == 3,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() => currentPageIndex = 3;

          Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: MY2Screen()));
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hello, i think u get me wrongly. I just edited my post can you see it again. Thank you

Comment: and with my code above. I did on another file bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigation()

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: 80,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => Card());
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = 1;
              });
            }),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => Card());
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = 2;
              });
            }),
        Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.abc, color: selectedIndex == 3 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => MyOrder(filterType: ''));
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = 3;
              });
            }),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: selectedIndex == 4 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => AccessoriesPage());
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = 4;
              });
            }),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

create variable selectedIndex

Comment: How do you create the variable? because if i set is int selectedIndex = 0, it will always be 0

Comment: Can you remote getx stuff from the snippet while OP is using  flutter navigator?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh what do you mean

Comment: you can put it in state class.

Comment: `Get.to(() => Card());` isnt not related to the question

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**